# How do I display text on a webpage upon clicking a 'Submit' button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've already got a form setup and everything.

```
<head>
<script language="javascript">
var i;
function fill_Cities(i){
var form1 = document.getElementById("form1a");
document.form1aa.Cities.options.length=0;
switch(i)
{
case 0:
form1.Cities.options[0] =new Option('calcutta','calcutta');
form1.Cities.options[1] =new Option('Delhi','Delhi');
form1.Cities.options[2] =new Option('Bombay','Bombay');
break;
case 1:
form1.Cities.options[0] =new Option('Alabama','Alabama');
form1.Cities.options[1] =new Option('Alaska','Alaska');
form1.Cities.options[2] =new Option('Arizona','Arizona');
form1.Cities.options[3] =new Option('Arkansas','Arkansas');
form1.Cities.options[4] =new Option('California','California');
form1.Cities.options[5] =new Option('Colorado','Colorado');
form1.Cities.options[6] =new Option('Connecticut','Connecticut');
form1.Cities.options[7] =new Option('Delaware','Delaware');
form1.Cities.options[8] =new Option('District of Columbia','District of Columbia');
form1.Cities.options[9] =new Option('Florida','Florida');
form1.Cities.options[10] =new Option('Georgia','Georgia');
form1.Cities.options[11] =new Option('Hawaii','Hawaii');
form1.Cities.options[12] =new Option('Idaho','Idaho');
form1.Cities.options[13] =new Option('Illinois','Illinois');
form1.Cities.options[14] =new Option('Indiana','Indiana');
form1.Cities.options[15] =new Option('Iowa','Iowa');
form1.Cities.options[16] =new Option('Kansas','Kansas');
form1.Cities.options[17] =new Option('Kentucky','Kentucky');
form1.Cities.options[18] =new Option('Louisiana','Louisiana');
form1.Cities.options[19] =new Option('Maine','Maine');
form1.Cities.options[20] =new Option('Maryland','Maryland');
form1.Cities.options[21] =new Option('Massachusetts','Massachusetts');
form1.Cities.options[22] =new Option('Michigan','Michigan');
form1.Cities.options[23] =new Option('Minnesota','Minnesota');
form1.Cities.options[24] =new Option('Mississippi','Mississippi');
form1.Cities.options[26] =new Option('Montana','Montana');
form1.Cities.options[27] =new Option('Nebraska','Nebraska');
form1.Cities.options[28] =new Option('Nevada','Nevada');
form1.Cities.options[29] =new Option('New Hampshire','New Hampshire');
form1.Cities.options[30] =new Option('New Jersey','New Jersey');
form1.Cities.options[31] =new Option('New Mexico','New Mexico');
form1.Cities.options[32] =new Option('New York','New York');
form1.Cities.options[33] =new Option('North Carolina','North Carolina');
form1.Cities.options[34] =new Option('North Dakota','North Dakota');
form1.Cities.options[35] =new Option('Ohio','Ohio');
form1.Cities.options[36] =new Option('Oklahoma','Oklahoma');
form1.Cities.options[37] =new Option('Oregon','Oregon');
form1.Cities.options[38] =new Option('Pennsylvania','Pennsylvania');
form1.Cities.options[39] =new Option('Rhode Island','Rhode Island');
form1.Cities.options[40] =new Option('South Carolina','South Carolina');
form1.Cities.options[41] =new Option('South Dakota','South Dakota');
form1.Cities.options[42] =new Option('Tennessee','Tennessee');
form1.Cities.options[43] =new Option('Texas','Texas');
form1.Cities.options[44] =new Option('Utah','Utah');
form1.Cities.options[45] =new Option('Vermont','Vermont');
form1.Cities.options[46] =new Option('Virginia','Virginia');
form1.Cities.options[47] =new Option('Washington','Washington');
form1.Cities.options[48] =new Option('West Virginia','West Virginia');
form1.Cities.options[49] =new Option('Wisconsin','Wisconsin');
form1.Cities.options[50] =new Option('Wyoming','Wyoming');

break;
case 2:
form1.Cities.options[0] =new Option('Essex','Essex');
form1.Cities.options[1] =new Option('London','London');
form1.Cities.options[2] =new Option('Perth','Perth');
}
}
</script>
</head>

<form name="form1aa" method="post" action="" id="form1a" >
<select name="country" onchange=" fill_Cities  (document.form1aa.country.selectedIndex); ">
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="U.S.A">U.S.A</option>
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
</select>
<select name="Cities">
</select>
</form>
```

I would like a click of a submit button, after the user selects a city to present some text. Preferably, in the webpage instead of a separate dialog box.

```
<input type="submit" />
```

I know how to create a submit button but I don't know how to link it to the cities form and display text.

Comment: What text do you want to display? Your question has too much code we don't need, and not enough information we do.

Comment: Just one line of text such as Pikmin. It's unique to each city, though.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your existing JS code:

```
form1.addEventListener('submit', function () {
  // Here you can add success message showing-code
  // like: document.getElementById("div_with_message").style.display = 'block';
  return false; // return false to prevent the browser from submitting. Assuming that is what you want.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following to get hold of the selected value of the cities drop-down and then use this value as needed in your application/page :

`var selectedValue = form1.Cities.options[form1.Cities.selectedIndex].value;`

And this can be done onsubmit of your form. Something like this:

Register your submit function:
`form1.onsubmit=submitForm;`

Function definition:

```
function submitForm()
{
var selectedValue = form1.Cities.options[form1.Cities.selectedIndex].value;
alert('value = ' + selectedValue); // for sample. change as you like
}
```